# Update Spyder on Winpython

Tags: python, pip, spyder

I started using Python with Winpython and Spyder interface version 3.x. Now that Spyder version 4.1.3 is available, I want to update from version 3.x to version 4.x without losing my spyder configuration and existing python installation. As I was already afraid, I made a backup of C:\WinPython-64bit-3.6.3.0Qt5, and then run the following commands in winpython control panel

```
pip uninstall Spyder
pip install --pre -U spyder
```

And now I am not able to start Spyder. Luckily I had a backup and I could recover. 
Can someone in the community recommend a safe way to update to spyder 4.x for Winpython installation?

Answer (score 2):

I advice to update WinPython to a recent version.
It's because of the depensies.

In WinPython i did today.

- Open WinPython Command Prompt.exe
- pip install Spyder==4.2.0

And my Spyder config still exists.

Comment: Great to know it works. Meanwhile, i did a fresh spyder installation using anaconda.